# Инстанировать пустой объект Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть метод

```
public static Object Instantiate(Object original,  
   Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);
```

Если мне необходимо создать пустой объект(как в редакторе Create Empty), мне нужно создавать префаб, давать ссылку на него или можно как то просто взять и создать пустой объект?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<T> _delta = new GameObject("name").AddComponent<T>();
```

Можете попробовать такой способ, где  это тип переменной, компонент.
Для создания пустого объекта нужно сделать:

```
GameObject _delta = new GameObject("name");
```